# FindMinimum wrongly giving a message that the function value is not a real number

Tags: mathematical-optimization, fitting

I am trying to use the method of moments to fit parameters to a distribution. This involves minimizing a function. This certainly gives real numbers, but FindMinimum gives an error message saying that the function value is not a real number at the starting values that I have chosen. I wondered if the StackExchange community might be able to identify what I am doing wrong or how I could solve this problem.

I've looked at answers to similar questions but they do not seem directly applicaable. I undertake to attempt to answer other peoples' questions.

The code is as follows:

```
a = 0;
b = 2;
c = -3;
d = 10;

funMomIT[Mu_Real,Sigma_Real,Nu_Real,Tau_Real] := (locdist = 
 TransformedDistribution[Mu + Log[x]*Sigma, 
x~BetaPrimeDistribution[Nu,Tau]]; 
 m1 = Moment[locdist, 1]; m2 = Moment[locdist, 2]; 
 m3 = Moment[locdist, 3]; 
 m4 = Moment[locdist, 4]; (m1 - a)^2 + (m2 - b)^2 + (m3 - c)^2 + (m4 - d)^2)
```

I've used a single tilde ~ instead of the correct double tilde for typesetting reasons.

When I type

```
FindMinimum[funMomIT, {{Mu, 1.0}, {Sigma, 0.0}, {Nu, 0.5}, {Tau, 0.5}}]
```

I get the message:

```
FindMinimum::nrnum: The function value findMomIT is not a real number 
 at {Mu,Sigma,Nu,Tau} = {1.,0.,0.5,0.5}. >>
```

But when I evaluate the function,

```
funMomIT[1.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5]
```

I get the value 99.

Plainly, then, the function is producing a real number at the evaluated point. Can anyone suggest what is going wrong here?

Note that I've tried different formulations, such as using a Module to run the function and evaluating the theoretical moments separately and then substituting them into the Module. These suffer from the same problem.

And I've also tried NMinimize. Same error message.

By the way, I'm aware of the function FindDistributionParameters. This is also failing for the MLE and various MoMs.

**Updated:** page 5 of the following paper gives formulae for the first four moments of the above distribution, and this appears to enable rapid solution (though this needs to be done by least squares). I'm still puzzled though why Mathematica is producing these errors on functions which are clearly producing real solutions.

"*Some Flexible Parametric Models for Partially
Adaptive Estimators of Econometric Models" by Theodossiou, Panayiotis; McDonald, James B.; Hansen, Christian B*.

**Also**, to update on the problems with FindDistributionParameters, if one uses the method of moments, and does not restrict the number of moments considered, one gets an error message that the equations for solving the method of moments are not consistent. If one restricts it to the first four parameters, Mathematica gives an error message that the parameters to be estimated are not the same as the parameters in the Method of Moments.

Comment: Your `FindMinimum` call **does not contain the right function**. Your function is called `funMomIT`, not `findMomIT`. Also, you need to include the calling parameters, i.e. `FindMinimum[funMomIT[Mu, Sigma, Nu, Tau], {{Mu, 1.0}, {Sigma, 0.0}, {Nu, 0.5}, {Tau, 0.5}}]`. It will then evaluate for a long time (I aborted it after a while).

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. That was a typo on my part in writing this up for stackexchange. I did use the correct function in the original code. (I did double check the corrected code and still get the same error)

Comment: Do you get the same error after including the parameters for `funMomIT` in `FindMinimum` as @MarcoB suggested?

Comment: @JimB Yes I did - in fact they were the ones that I originally included in my call to the function.

Comment: By the way, if it helps, the transformed distribution is EGB2. There is a library for this in R, for example, but not Mathematica. I'm trying to validate the result that I am getting in R.

Comment: `FindMinimum[
 funMomIT[Mu, Sigma, Nu, 
  Tau], {{Mu, 1.0}, {Sigma, 0.0}, {Nu, 0.5}, {Tau, 0.5}}]` seems to be off and running just fine.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel Lichtblau.  I agree with that answer.I seem to have arrived at the same conclusion simultaneously. Will mark yours as the answer - if I can find the legendary checkmark sign!

Answer (score 2):

The answer would appear to be that you need to include the variables in the specification of the function that you are trying to optimize. So I should have written:

```
FindMinimum[funMomIT[Mu,Sigma,Nu,Tau], {{Mu, 1.0}, {Sigma, 0.0}, {Nu, 0.5}, {Tau, 0.5}}]
```

I had apparently incorrectly used:

```
FindMinimum[funMomIT, {{Mu, 1.0}, {Sigma, 0.0}, {Nu, 0.5}, {Tau, 0.5}}]
```

That this will not work is not clear in my version at least of the Mathematica help files.

Comment: Also to add that I found that Maximum Likelihood worked better.